# excel 2016 text import wizard missing file origin options

Tags: utf-8, windows-10, excel-2016

Yesterday got new pc with windows 10 pro office 2016 and having trouble with excel 2016. Trying to get external data from text file. Text import wizard only shows two choices in file origin drop down list (Windows ANSI and Macintosh) so there is no way to get UTF8 file to show correctly! any ideas?

screenshot here:
[image]

Comment: after several days thinking about this, several reinstalls and pointless hours with online microsoft support figured out this... i don't know what office 2016 fcuks up in windows 10 after installing but running sfc /scannow to fix windows system files file origin options in text import wizard are back!!! just to be sure that was not a faint luck did a double check - did clean install of windows 10 pro and immediately installed office 2016 home and business and of course file origin options are missing but after sfc /scannow everything seems to work fine!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several days thinking about this, several reinstalls and pointless hours with online microsoft support figured out this... i don't know what office 2016 fcuks up in windows 10 after installing but running sfc /scannow to fix windows system files file origin options in text import wizard are back!!! just to be sure that was not a faint luck did a double check - did clean install of windows 10 pro and immediately installed office 2016 home and business and of course file origin options are missing but after sfc /scannow everything seems to work fine!!!